# navigate between pages Google Search with selenium - Java

Tags: java, selenium

How do I search for something on Google , click on the link , then return to the search and click the following link ( without repeating the already links clicked ) and after the links that the page finished , navigate to the page 2 and repeat the same steps in succession?

So far I could go to the first link, go to the page and return to the list of links searched only.

```
    package Search;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class GoogleSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/Users/paulo.roberto/Documents/eclipse/Selenium/IEDriverServer.exe");
              DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
              caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
              WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);          
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

            driver.get("https://www.google.com.br");

            driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("test");
            driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

            WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("resultStats"))); 


            // find the number of pages
            int size = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[valign='top'] > td")).size();
            for(int j = 1 ; j < size ; j++) {
                if (j > 1) {// we don't need to navigate to the first page
                    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[aria-label='Page " + j + "']")).click(); // navigate to page number j
                }

                String pagesearch = driver.getCurrentUrl();

                List<WebElement> findElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']//h3/a"));
                System.out.println(findElements.size());

                for(int i=0;i<findElements.size();i++){
                    findElements= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']//h3/a"));                
                    findElements.get(i).click(); 

                    driver.navigate().to(pagesearch);
                    // or driver.navigate().back();
                }
            }



    }

}
```

message on the console:

> ```
> Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
> 2.48.0.0
> Listening on port 37101
> 10
> 10
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 0
>   at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
>   at Search.GoogleSearch.main(GoogleSearch.java:48)
> ```

Comment: Why do you want to reload the google search results multiple times? Load it only once, you have the result that you can process further. I would use JSoup for page analysis instead of Selenium.

Comment: @tak3shi 
In fact , I 'm learning selenium and so creating some code as an example.
desire has not utilizaqr the jsoup , just want to be able to navigate through the URLs and then move on to the next search pages and click on the next link , that's all .

Comment: ok, thats fine, but google will detect the automated access and at some point you will receive a captcha page instead of the search results.

Comment: Did this exception is in other drivers (firefox, chromedriver) ??

Comment: @SkorpEN IE11, Firefox e Chrome

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested loops. One to navigate between results pages and one to click on results

```
// find the number of pages
int size = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[valign='top'] > td")).size();
for(int j = 1 ; j < size ; j++) {
    if (j > 1) {// we don't need to navigate to the first page
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[aria-label='Page " + j + "']")).click(); // navigate to page number j
    }

    String pagesearch = driver.getCurrentUrl();

    List<WebElement> findElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']//h3/a"));
    System.out.println(findElements.size());

    for(int i=0;i<findElements.size();i++){
        findElements= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='rso']//h3/a"));                
        findElements.get(i).click(); 

        driver.navigate().to(pagesearch);
        // or driver.navigate().back();
    }
}
```

Comment: He correctly navigated to some extent, but on the third page stood in one of the accessed links and did not return to the list of search , you tell me how to solve it , to keep it going through the pages correctly?

The variable pagesearch {String pagesearch = driver.getCurrentUrl();} records url of the search, but I think she is recording only the initial search URL and not the following page , can it be?

Comment: Shows no error in the execution and not on the island , is just caught in the accessed link.

Comment: @PauloSilva You have to options, capture the url in the external loop (added to my answer) or use `driver.navigate().back();` instead of `driver.navigate().to(pagesearch);`

Comment: I used his new example with driver.navigate().to( pagesearch); and for some reason he goes to the second page , click 01 link and then returns to the page 1 and click again on all already links clicked before, strange, would have some way of treating this behavior, so it click all the links on page 1 , scroll to page 2 and do the same , sme repeat the links?

Comment: @PauloSilva Put the `String pagesearch = driver.getCurrentUrl();` after `if (j > 1)` condition, that way it will move to next page before taking the url.

Comment: It is giving an error when it comes on the first page , oddly enough they click some links and not others , then when you change the page it simply , already researched on various sites and I am trying to understand how to solve this , but without success.

I ask from the updated with the code and the console error.